# CQRS - separate command and event handlers

Tags: cqrs

Going over some [really interesting demo CQRS code here](https://gist.github.com/hyrmn/3200053/raw/39ae14e4226d5e0d032690bf0e37e75286d2a1f7/EndToEndTests.cs) commands and handlers are split in to separate interfaces.

```
public interface CommandHandler<in T>
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

public interface EventHandler<in T>
{
    void Handle(T @event);
}
```

I am auto-wiring the commands and events, it seems there *may* be a limitation with membus where it can only wireup CommandHandlers or EventHandlers, but either way it has me thinking:

Given both interfaces have a Handle method, what is the idea of splitting the commands and events in this way, when a single common command/event `Handler` interface could be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is semantic - an event and command are semantically different message types and it can be beneficial to make that difference explicit. The benefits can be both in terms of organization and functionality since each message type may have unique handling requirements.

Comment: Also over time a single command may end up producing more than one event or even one type of event as a result of it's handling.

Comment: I realize that this is a very old comment, but I just wanted to mention that a single command producing one event *or* (exclusive) another depending on some condition is a bit of an anti-pattern. The same command should always result in the same event (or same multiple events), barring some state checks/constrains that the command handler via the aggregate knows about.